# QML baseline alignment without using a layout

Tags: qml, alignment, qtquick2, qtquickcontrols2, baseline

I want to use baseline alignment anchor without using any fancy RowLayouts, etc. I want to use bottom anchor of a label be anchored with the baseline of the text edit. I thought, that baseline of controls without text is a top anchor, and for controls with text is somewhere between top and bottom anchors. But for my TextEdit it is the top anchor, which is unexpected

```
        Rectangle {
            width: 320
            height: 100
            border.width:  1

            Label {
                id: l
                text: "Description "
                height: 40
                anchors.bottom: te1.baseline
            }
            TextField {
                id: te1
                text: "Some test"
                height: 35
                anchors.left: l.right
                y: parent.height /  2
            }
        }
```

I tried demos with Qt5&6 and with default controls and QtQuick.Controls. By some reason the baseline of the textedit is the top. Why?

[image]

**Update**: The desired result I put on the screenshot below the actual one. I tried to calculate manually offsets for the label using the sizes of controls and font's metrics. Sadly, I still have magic constants there, which is not portable between various machines

```
FontMetrics {
    id: fontMetrics
    font.family: "Arial"
    font.pointSize: defaultFontSize
}

Rectangle {
    width: 320
    height: 120
    border.width:  1
    Text {
        id: l3
        text: "Description:"
        height: 15
        width: 150
        x: 0
        y: te3.y + te3.height / 2 - fontMetrics.height / 2 - 4
        font.family: "Arial";
        font.pointSize: defaultFontSize
    }
    TextField {
        id: te3
        text: "asdf2222"
        font.family: "Arial"
        font.pointSize: defaultFontSize
        background: Rectangle { color: "lightgray" }
        height: 50
        width: 100
        y: parent.height /  2
        anchors.left: l3.right
    }
}
```

Comment: Looks to me as though you have competing and/or incomplete anchoring. The TextField is trying to anchor to the right of the Label, which is trying to anchor to the bottom of the Textfield. How do you want it to look?

Comment: @mzimmers I enchanced my question with desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does  below get the job done for you?

```
Rectangle {
  width: 320
  height: 200
  border.width:  1
  color: "black"
  Label {
    id: l
    height: 40
    text: "Description: "
    anchors.baseline: te1.baseline
    // y: te1.y
  }
  TextField {
    id: te1
    height: 35
    text: "Some test"
    anchors.left: l.right
    y: parent.height /  2
  }
}
```